# Do we have a SE site about marine engineering?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, site-proposal

There's a site on Area 51 about Engineering, but I don't know if we have like a branch of that site talking about marine engineering. You know, like, the building of big ships, oil rigs, etc.

Comment: What would a good example question be?

Comment: @DnrDevil How is a cruise ship built? How does a ship float? Where do they have their fuel tanks? How do oil platforms deal with storms? There could be many good questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Engineering beta site](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) accepts questions on marine engineering.  It currently has four questions tagged with the [marine engineering tag](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marine-engineering):

- [What mechanism in the radar that enables the switch between transmission and reception?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/6664/5625)
- [Purpose of spheres and fins on submarine propeller](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/1908/5625)
- [How to divert solids from a downward vertical pipe](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/537/5625)
- [Below what Froude number can I neglect wave-making resistance on a vessel?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/231/5625)

Plus there's this one:

- [Why would you launch a large ship by dropping it sideways?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/7536/5625)

That's not even counting the [**176** questions](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluid-mechanics) tagged with `fluid-mechanics` and [**22**](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluid-mechanics+hydraulics) on `hydraulics`.